# Kubernetes Dashboard (from Helm chart) behind Cloudflare Tunnel - How to fix TLS bad certificate error?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cloudflare

I have successfully installed `cloudflared` in my K3s cluster and am running a bunch of services through several subdomains that point to the tunnel. That works like a charm.

Now I would like to create another subdomain that points to the Kubernetes Dashboard service. I can access other services with ease through the Cloudflare Tunnel, but not the Kubernetes Dashboard service because contrary to the other services it exposes HTTPS, thus I'm facing a "TLS bad certificate" error.

How can I solve this error? Is disabling HTTPS/TLS on the service a viable option? Encryption and certificate handling should be done by Cloudflare already, if I'm not mistaken.